# python 3.4 modules can be install because numpy

Tags: numpy, python-3.4

I try to install some python module like vispy , pandas , pyqtgraph... and I got some errors :

```
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc9_support.py", line 52,
 in query_vcvarsall
        return unpatched['query_vcvarsall'](version, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcva
rsall
        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
    ValueError: ['path']
```

I used this command :

```
pip3.4 install -U numpy
```

Seam the problem come from numpy module .
How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix with this Wheels and this files :

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#NumPy